# Save Python Idle Shell

Tags: python, shell

I'm using python 3.11.0.
Right now in order to save the python idle shell I'm doing it manually `File->Save As`
I'm looking for a command to automate the saving of the python idle shell.

Comment: Does `ctrl`[+`shift`]+`s` fit your definition of a command?

Comment: you can enable autosave in settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable auto save in settings or use `Ctrl + s` to save file.

[image]

Comment: I'd like to select also where I want to save this log. That's why I'm more interested in command that should be added at the end of a script.

Comment: @martinmistere save what log? save the output of program in a file?

Comment: yes correct. I want to save it into a folder which may change each time

Comment: @martinmistere if you are looking to save the log of your program into different files. You can do something like this. I dont see the need to automate saving via a script.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python